# How can I create a batch file using ffmpeg and screenshots?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have over 700 files that I need to take a screenshot at a specific time. I have been doing this one by one, but it is very time consuming. How could I do this with an ffmpeg batch file?

I also need the output of the file to be named the same as the video input.

I've been using this command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:45 -i "input.Mp4" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "output.jpg"
```

Comment: Do you need to take all the screenshots at '00:03:45` or does it vary between files?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as batch file

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -ss 00:03:45 -i "%%i" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "%%~ni.jpg"
```

Comment: @Mulvya Your syntax (double %) only work in batch files. Use `%i` if typing interactively.

Comment: @ACatInLove  I know. I meant the batch file the OP wants, not the statement itself.

Comment: @Mulvya S/he could be confused about what EXACTLY to do.

Comment: @enefranco, if it crashed then there should be an error.  We can't help you unless you help us by telling us what error was output. All that was done with your code was to encapsulate it inside a `FOR` command.  If it is not working then you are not describing your problem correctly.